# Nodemon crashed while setting up express server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

while setting up an express server, I tried to run it, bt is showing an error, the exact phrase I typed on the terminal is (npm run dev), I checked whether my port is already under work or if there same name file in my laptop and whether my package.json is in the same folder of my server.js .. nothing is working, being a newbie it's my first project. I would be most grateful if the community can help me.

[server.js window - showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62SSe.jpg)

[package.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3qMB.jpg)

Comment: Do you using nvm?

Comment: nope i am not using nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to require `express` and your `package.json` doesn't include it so I assume you don't have it installed

`npm install express` should fixt it

Comment: yes bro it got resolved ...thanks bro